# Repeated output of the same digit in for loop

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, user-input

When I define a function of reverse, it not only reverses the digits but it prints it thrice.
How can I get only one reversed answered?

```
def reverse_int():
    num=(input("Enter a 3-digit number: "))
    for number in num:
        print (num[::-1])
reverse_int()
```

Comment: Get rid of the for loop, which causes the print to be called thrice (the length of your input) and just write the print separately

Answer (score -1):

```py
def reverse_int():
    num=(input("Enter a 3-digit number: \n"))
    print (num[::-1])
reverse_int()
```

Comment: It is not recommended to write only parts of code without textual context information. Can you improve your response by also describing why your code changes help to solve the problem?